# How do I get a debugging engine for Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am getting the following error launching a script from ESTK:
Cannot execute script. Target Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5 provides no engine for debugging.

I have also posted this question on the Adobe forums.

I have been working on the script for about 2 weeks now. Something happend with adobe last night. This morning, I had to re-sign-in to my CC apps. And rebuild desktop shortcuts. Now, Exendscript can't connect to Photoshop.

I can still target PS from the ESTK. This is only happening on OS X, my Windows workflow is still OK.

Any direction in troubleshooting at this point would be helpful.